# where is core-default.xml file?

Tags: hadoop, mapr

I'm interested in value of `fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled` parameter in my mapr cluster.

I know the value is set in core-default.xml (if not overwritten by core-site.xml) but I cannot find core-default.xml file. Any suggestions where it can be?

Is there any way to check the current value of parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where is core-default.xml file?

It is in resources of `hadoop-common`; https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/resources/core-default.xml

So in this case you will be able to find it inside jar file of `hadoop-common`; the jar can be found in `/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-<version>/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-<version>.jar`

I have extracted the jar and list the files;

```
[... ~]$ jar xf ./hadoop-common-<version>.jar
[... ~]$ ll
-rw-rw-r--  1  mapr mapr   1041 Mar 15 18:36 common-version-info.properties
-rw-rw-r--  1  mapr mapr  64287 Mar 15 18:06 core-default.xml
...
```

> Is there any way to check the current value of parameter?

Yes there is. In order to grep the property by means of `hadoop` utilities, please run the following command;

```
hadoop org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration | grep "fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled"
```